# Java linked list how to make a private method to handle searching

Tags: java, linked-list

I trying and need help on how to create a private method to search a singly linked list.

My private search method is all the way at the bottom, how can I create a private method so i can then use it in an add/delete method?

I have been trying to do this for hours and I can't seem to get it right, i want to make a private search method to avoid loops later on in my other methods such as find add delete

```
public class LinkedBag<T> {

private Node first;

private int n;

public LinkedBag() {
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}

public int size() {
    return n;
}

public void add(T item) {
    Node oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    n++;
}

public int search(T item) {
    if(item == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot search null");
    }
    Node x = first;
    int c = size() - 1;
    while(x != null) {
        if(x.item.equals(item)) {
            return c;
        }
        x = x.next;
        c--;
    }
    return -1;
}

private class Node {
    private T item;

    private Node next;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedBag<Integer> intBag = new LinkedBag<>();
    intBag.add(1);
    intBag.add(2);
    intBag.add(3);
    System.out.println(intBag.search(1) == 0);
    System.out.println(intBag.search(2) == 1);
    System.out.println(intBag.search(3) == 2);
    System.out.println(intBag.search(4) == -1);
}
```

}

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? This is pretty vague and broad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't know how to make a private search method or two to obtain the reference to the given node and the one before it

Comment: If it's a list, then you need somewhere to hold the members of the list, say an array or something.  If you want to avoid loops then you can hold the members in a hashed `Collection` such as `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a search method in a single linked list which returns the position of the item or e.g. -1 in case the item was not found.

This search method will need to loop from the first node through its tailing nodes sequentially, extracts the item associated to each node and uses the `equals` method to try to find a match with the search item.

Here is a possible implementation in Java:

```
public int search(T item) {
    Node x = first;
    int c = size() - 1;
    while(x != null) {
        if(x.item.equals(item)) {
            return c;
        }
        x = x.next;
        c--;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Below is a full example of how you can do it in a simple linked list with minimal generics support. Included is also a main method with a minimal unit test to prove the concept:

```
public class LinkedBag<T> {

    private Node first;

    private int n;

    public LinkedBag() {
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return n;
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
        n++;
    }

    public int search(T item) {
        if(item == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot search null");
        }
        Node x = first;
        int c = size() - 1;
        while(x != null) {
            if(x.item.equals(item)) {
                return c;
            }
            x = x.next;
            c--;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private class Node {
        private T item;

        private Node next;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBag<Integer> intBag = new LinkedBag<>();
        intBag.add(1);
        intBag.add(2);
        intBag.add(3);
        System.out.println(intBag.search(1) == 0);
        System.out.println(intBag.search(2) == 1);
        System.out.println(intBag.search(3) == 2);
        System.out.println(intBag.search(4) == -1);
    }
}
```